# Laravel 5.7 : How to make JSON post request in guzzle?

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle, geoserver

This is my code, I want to make a new store in Geoserver

```
 public function post_store(String $name) {

      $client = new Client();
     $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/' . $name . '/datastores', [
         'auth' => ['admin', 'geoserver'],
         'json' => [
             'dataStore' => [
                 'name' => $name,
                 'connectionParameter' => [
                     'entry' => [
                         '@key' => 'host', '$' => 'localhost',
                         '@key' => 'port', '$' => 5432,
                         '@key' => 'database', '$' => 'nyc',
                         '@key' => 'user', '$' => 'shee',
                         '@key' => 'passwd', '$' => 'postgres',
                         '@key' => 'dbtype', '$' => 'postgis',
                     ]
                 ]
             ]
         ] 

     ]);
 }
```

and the result is error

```
   Server error: `POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/pertanian/datastores` resulted in a `500 Server Error` response: <html> <head> <meta http- equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> <title>Error 500 
   Server Error</title> (truncated...)
```

But I have tried with POSTMAN using JSON code:

```
  {
 "dataStore": {
   "name": "nyc",
   "connectionParameters": {
     "entry": [
       {"@key":"host","$":"localhost"},
       {"@key":"port","$":"5432"},
       {"@key":"database","$":"nyc"},
       {"@key":"user","$":"shee"},
       {"@key":"passwd","$":"postgres"},
       {"@key":"dbtype","$":"postgis"}
     ]
   }
 }
  }
```

And it works.

Anyone can help me ? What should I do with my code ? ._.
Thankyou before

Comment: You used `connectionParameter` instead of `connectionParameters` in the request body.

Comment: You may need to check if you have the right parameter and you do it correctly.

Comment: Please add the error response from the server if you have it. It returns 500 error but looks like the message has been truncated.

Comment: I already check the parameter.. but it is still errorr
Erorr is located in `GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ServerException (500)`
Is it wrong at the guzzle ??

thankyou before

Comment: Error 500 means the server is rejecting your request. Check the *server's* log file to determine the cause. It  may be able to provide a hint of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable $username=admin and other $password=geoserver and then use those two variables in the auth array. That works for me